# mongodb terminates on any find command

Tags: django, mongodb, find, geospatial

I keep getting thrown out of my mongo session when I do queries like find. I am specifically trying to do a geo query (`db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] } } )` but the issue seems to be with any find query.

I get this error:

```
Sun Dec 18 16:33:12 terminate() called in shell, printing stack:
0x80a8bc0 0x809dbd2 0xb77ca283 0xb77ca2bf 0xb77ca40e 0x80ecdd0 0x813b9c4 0x812e410 0xb7411450 
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x30) [0x80a8bc0]
 mongo(_Z11myterminatev+0x52) [0x809dbd2]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaf283) [0xb77ca283]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaf2bf) [0xb77ca2bf]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xaf40e) [0xb77ca40e]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo9uassertedEiPKc+0x130) [0x80ecdd0]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo9Convertor8toStringEP8JSString+0x2a4) [0x813b9c4]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo12native_printEP9JSContextjPy+0xb0) [0x812e410]
 /usr/lib/libmozjs185.so.1.0(+0xac450) [0xb7411450]
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

As a side note, I am inserting into mongo using a django-mongo engine interface.

Comment: and the same query but from python?

Comment: I tried doing the work I needed through django's `python manage.py shell` but I ran into some other issues there. It seems to be a mongo issue to me, so I posted the relevant mongo stuff.

Comment: How about using the `pymongo` module to connect and do queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like either your database is corrupted or contains invalid UTF-8 string. Can you try to repair or verify your data?

BTW, Geo query shouldn't use javascript. Are you compiling the code yourself? Stacktrace doesn't look right too. It seems to use JS 1.8.5 instead of JS 1.7.

Comment: I did a fresh install, and got everything to work. Thank you for tipping me off about possible corruption